# Assigning specific menu administration rights for roles in Drupal

Tags: php, html, drupal, drupal-6

I'm trying to give one of my roles the administrative rights to add/remove content in a specific menu (but not all menus). I think I found a module that should enable something like this, http://drupalmodules.com/module/delegate-menu-administration

I've followed the instructions, added the role to my user, checked the "administer some menus" value for that role and checked the "Make admin" field for that role and specific menu in Menus. I also gave the role permissions to change page and story content.

However, it still won't let the user add any new content it creates in any menu, and I get an error message saying:

> warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/martin/www/drupal/modules/delegate_menu_admin/delegate_menu_admin.module on line 346.

Line 346 looks like this:

```
foreach ($form['menu']['parent']['#options'] as $key => $value) {
```

I did a `print_r($form);` in the file just before it and there's no such array that I can see:

```
[menu] => Array
        (
            [#access] => 1
            [delete] => Array
                (
                    [#access] => 
                )
        )
```

When I gave the role "administer menu" permissions, nothing extra was printed at all, leading me to the assumption that the delegate_menu_admin.module file is not used at all while both the "administer menu" and the "administer some menus" (from the delegate-menu-administration module) permissions are set!

Is this some incompatibility between the module because of some Drupal update?

Comment: @Martin: changed Python tag to PHP tag.

Comment: have you added your role to the given menu in admin/build/menu?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why the delegate-menu-administration module is not working, but I found another module, Menu Admin per Menu, that seems to work.